# How can I adjust the position and appearance of chktex linting in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, word-wrap

I am using VS Code and LaTeX-Workshop with the chktex linter. It works very well, however line wrap does not function with it. Currently, when it displays a warning, it does so at the end of the line that the warning is on, like so (warnings displayed in orange):

[image]

This poses a problem when I am looking at my document, since sometimes it is cut off. Is there a way to make it obey line wrapping, or possibly just put the warning on a separate line? I want to be able to see the whole warning. I've tried adjusting the line wrapping cutoff and it doesn't do anything. I've also looked at the .chktexrc file and I don't think anything will work there since it seems to be an intrinsic VS Code or extension issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a sub-case of the following bug report ticket on VS Code's GitHub repo: [Inline text adornments break word wrapping
#32856](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32856). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

I'm not sure where exactly the related source code is in the LaTeX extension, but it might be https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/blob/master/src/components/locator.ts, where I see a call to `setDecorations`.